# Created dummy python server in company's network, while trying to see a file on server getting "page cannot be displayed"

Tags: python

I am amateur and have created a dummy python server on my system which uses my company's network. 
when I am trying to view a file on the my server, the browser says page cannot be displayed.

this is my code

```
import socket
serverPort = 5000
serverSocket = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
serverSocket.bind((host,serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(5)
print ('Server is ready to recieve')
while True:
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    print ('got connection from'), addr
    data = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
    print ('server received', repr(data))
    filename='helloworld.html'
    f=open(filename,'rb')
    bytesToSend= f.read(1024)
    connectionSocket.send(bytesToSend)
    while bytesToSend !='':
        bytesToSend= f.read(1024)
        connectionSocket.send(bytesToSend)
        print('sent',repr(bytesToSend))
        l= f.read(1024)
    f.close

print ('done sending')
connectionSocket.send('thank you for connecting')
connectionSocket.close()
```

i used internet explorer and using the url

```
http://IPAddress:5000/helloworld
```

Received "page cannot be found error" on the broswer. 
Could you please suggest how can i fix it.

Comment: Did the server print 'got connection from' ? You may have to open the port in windows firewall.

Comment: You have a couple of bugs including `l= f.read(1024)` should be `bytesToSend=read(1024)`. And you may want to `serverSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)` before the bind. Check to see if your server is crashing. And also consider binding to `"0.0.0.0"` instead of the gethostname thing so that you catch other interfaces such as the 'localhost' internal network on your machine.

Comment: Thank @tdelaney for replying.  And no my server did not even print got connection from. _*How can I open the port in the windows firewall?*_  For the rest of code correction I will try it again making the changes and would let you know if my problem is solved.